# Obtain all the columns from my model in django

Tags: django, django-models

I want to obtain all the info from one table of my database in django, I'm doing this,

```
from django.shortcuts import render
# Create your views here.
from Platform_App.models import Fleet

def list_fleets(request):
    fleet = Fleet.objects.all()
    return render(request, template_name='fleets.html', context={'Fleet':fleet})
```

But it shows an error in the line below, concretely in `fleets`.

```
fleet = Fleet.objects.all()
```

It says,

> class fleets has no objects member

My `model` is the following:

```
from django.db import models

class Fleet(models.Model):
    fleet_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    fleet_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True, null=True)
```

If `fleet = Fleet.objects.all()` is not correct, how I have to do it to take all the columns of my table??

Probably a easy question, but I'm newbie. Thank you very much!!!!

Comment: have you added the app in `settings.py` INSTALLED_APPS ?

Comment: `fleet = fleets.objects.all()` will return objects are present in the database, Do you have any object of fleets? It will not return column names.  @Lleims

Comment: @MassimoCosta yes I added it

Comment: @MehaParekh sorry but I'm not sure if I'm understanding you, I have what I showed in the post

Comment: @Lleims do you have entries in the database for `fleets` table?

Comment: @MehaParekh yesss, I have 2 fleets with id and name. No description

Comment: Hey, there are some methods to name a model. In your case it should be Fleet. The model definition is a class, so always use CapWords convention (no underscores). Always name your models using singular. And i guess you should name those variables in lowercase.

Comment: Then, you get a queryset object by this `fleets.objects.all()`. But you want only column names, right?

Comment: Show us your entire file *Platform_App/models.py*, something else is wrong here.

Comment: @Liems, where you see the error ? IDE or running TEST ?

Comment: @MassimoCosta IDE

Comment: @dirkgroten I just have one model right now, that's all

Comment: you're importing `fleets` but your model is `Fleets`? And how can your import `fleets` without error if you never define it in the *models.py* file? The reason I'm asking you to show the entire files is that `fleets.objects.all()` should just work (if `fleets` is a `Model` and you didn't override the default manager). So I want to see the full files. The code you're showing here **cannot** produce your error.

Comment: Hey @Lleims , dont mind. Happens in  SO. I have added an answer. Just try

Comment: @dirkgroten this is a mistake just here, sorry

Comment: @Lleims After changing, name of model and migrations do you get a queryset object?

Comment: @Lleims again your current code would give another error: `fleets` is not defined (in `fleets.objects.all()`) since you import `Fleets`. You **have to show the code that produces this error**, i.e. copy&paste your code. Nothing you showed until now can produce your error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this [link](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tips/2018/02/10/django-tip-22-designing-better-models.html) and the below codes will help you:

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Fleet(models.Model):
    fleet_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    fleet_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True, null=True)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
# Create your views here.
from Platform_App.models import Fleet

def fleet_list(request):
    fleet = Fleet.objects.all()
    return render(request, template_name='fleets.html', context = {'fleets':fleet})
```

and in your template fleets.html

```
{% for fleet in fleets %}
```

FYI: Let me know if this worked.